# Why did Paul's plans get denied?

Tags: plot-explanation, motherless-brooklyn

In [Motherless Brooklyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motherless_Brooklyn_(film)), Paul is a genius engineer and idealist. He presents a new electricity grid plan to his brother Moses, who claims it's brilliant and that it would benefit the both of them. However,

> The next day, Moses denies Paul's plans out of spite,

I'm not sure why. What spite? **What is Moses' motivation to refuse Paul's plan?** Does it have to do with the fact that it was Paul's idealism that cause this whole situation with Laura being associated to Moses, Moses getting blackmailed, etc etc?

Comment: You may get a better answer directing this to people who have read the book, where this may be dealt with in more detail.